# Are the files linked with download anchor elements downloaded on page load?

Tags: html

In my webpage I have link:

```
<a href="content" download>Download PDF</a>
```

Am I correct to assume that the content is not being transferred (loaded) until it is requested?

Comment: Yes, that is generally how link elements work.

Comment: If you download the files, you'll notice that it doesn't download immediately; it takes a few seconds, meaning the content "transfers" after the download is initiated

Comment: @Rojo the thing is that sometimes when downloading from other webpages, it seemed like part of the download was already done (not starting from zero or downloading incredibly fast) so it made me wonder and I found no answer in Mozilla documentation (probably because it is that obvious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until being clicked or activated in other way by user, this link will wait for its time.